# Using a variable as a key to call a value from a table

Tags: variables, lua, key

In my code I'm trying to make a script in which you steal a car, deliver it, and get a certain amount of money for that car. I made a table where I define how much money you get per car. I can get the keys to work, so my script does recognize the cars.

```
local cars = {

    ["panto"] = '5',
    ["oracle"] = '10',
    ["felon"] = '15',
    ["sentinel"] = '20',
    ["ratloader"] = '25',
    ["dune"] = '30',
    ["buccaneer"] = '35'

}
```

This is the table, which I then convert;

```
local voertuigen = {}
for k,_ in pairs(cars) do
    table.insert(voertuigen, k)
```

I'm dutch, so I use some dutch variables, kinda confusing, still working on it ;)

```
voertuig = (voertuigen[math.random(1, #voertuigen)])
```

This part is written inside an if statement, but that isn't the issue, when I try to reference to `voertuig` as a key, since it's a variable in which the key is stored, it doesn't work;

```
salaris = cars.voertuig
```

When I was trying to trouble shoot myself, I saw that `print(cars.oracle)` (One of the keys in the table) did work but when I use

```
voertuig = oracle
print(cars.voertuig)
```

It returns:
`SCRIPT ERROR: @carjob/cj_client.lua:114: attempt to concatenate a nil value (upvalue 'voertuig')`

I hope I provided enough code for you to understand, and I hope that one of you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note the difference between strings values and variables.

```
local a = {"name"}
```

`a.name` is syntactic sugar for `a["name"]`

in your example `vertuig = oracle` is equivalent to `voertuig= nil` because `oracle` is a nil value.

`cars.voertuig`is also nil. Because you never assign a value to `cars["voertuig"]`.

You want to do something like:

```
vertuig = "oracle"
print(cars[voertuig])
```

where `cars[voertuig]` resolves to `cars["oracle"]`

Please refer to the Lua manual and find out how to properly index table values.

```
voertuig = (voertuigen[math.random(1, #voertuigen)])
salaris = cars[voertuig]
```

Also use local variables wherever possible.

Comment: So `voertuig` should be a string to be recognized and to not return `nil`?

Comment: Nvm, this fixed it, thanks for making things clear! :)

Comment: your key is a string so you need that string to get your value. another string or anything lese won"t give you a value from your table. of course you can use other things as keys. even variables or other tables, not only strings. just read the manual